# How do I create a notification url endpoint for microsoft graph api change notifications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get change notifications for users using microsoft graph api. For testing purpose I have been using ngrok as suggested by many.

But now I want to use the real notification url to test my code.

How do I do it? The microsoft documentation says "This URL must make use of the HTTPS protocol".

Do I create an endpoint in azure or what are the other options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The notificationUrl is just your proxy URL. See the example here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/hands-on-labs/blob/master/O3653/O3653-19%20WebHooks/Lab.md

The one in the sample using ngrok looks like:

```
https://74c48253.ngrok.io/notification/listen
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Power Automate Instant Cloud Flow with the trigger as "When an HTTP request is received" and the subsequent steps could include emails with the details of the notification.
When you save the flow a URI will be generated which you can copy and use as your Graph change notification URI.